# Sencha command packages vs open tooling packages

Tags: extjs

Is there an easy way to migrate sencha command packages to open tooling packages?  I tried to use the ext-gen migrate command but this did not work because there is not workspace.json in an sencha command package.

I also noticed there is no way to generate an open tooling package template like you can in sencha command.  sencha generate template XXXX.

Is there a difference between an app and a package in new open tooling?  Is everything a package?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way to migrate a package or workspace - only individual applications. The only way that works is to create a new package and move the code in manually.

And, yes, everything is now a NPM package. You'll need to learn that to work out how to package, share, and distribute your code. I can't help with that, as I'm still trying to learn it as well.